# Overlapping of images while pasting from one to another excel using VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, copy-paste

I am trying to paste few images from one excel to another, but facing an issue in it. the images are overlapping on each other., and even the size is very small.Below is the code of what i have tried.

```
If Source = ESNAME Then
    Dim shp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape
    Dim lCol As Integer = 0
    Dim I As Integer = 1
    '~~> Loop through all shapes and find the last col of the shape
    For Each shp In WS.Shapes
        If shp.BottomRightCell.Column > lCol Then _
        lCol = shp.BottomRightCell.Column



        With WS
            '~~> Find actual last Row
            Dim LastRow As Integer = I
            Dim LastColumn As Integer = I
            Dim str As String = "B" & I & "@"

            '~~> Check if we have the correct last columnm
            If LastColumn < lCol Then LastColumn = lCol
            .Range(str.Replace("@", ":") & Split(.Cells(, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & LastRow).Copy()
            Dim sheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
            sheet = Nothing
            sheet = DW.Worksheets(1)
            sheet.Paste()


        End With
        I = I + 1
    Next
End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to paste the shapes one below the other or next to each other?

Comment: i need two pics in a row, total i have 6 images, the 2, which i need in a row are coming properly, but the ones which should come in another row are been over lapped.

Comment: 2 then below that 2 and below that 2?

Comment: yeah exactly, and even the size is coming of one cell.i need bigger images.

Comment: Also last question. Would there be any other shapes in the sheet before you copy the shapes?

Comment: no. the sheet is empty.

Comment: any way what to do ahead ?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry was out... Posting an answer in few minutes....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41406/discussion-between-user2703389-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Hope it is sorted now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your Workbook1 looks like this

[image]

Try this code (TRIED AND TESTED in VS 2010 + OFFICE 2010)

**Code**

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        '~~> Define your Excel Objects
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook1 As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim xlWorkBook2 As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim xlWorkSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
        Dim xlWorkSheet2 As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

        '~~> Display Excel
        xlApp.Visible = True

        '~~> Open relevant excel files and set your objects
        xlWorkBook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\book1.xlsx")
        xlWorkSheet1 = xlWorkBook1.Sheets("Sheet1")

        xlWorkBook2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\book2.xlsx")
        xlWorkSheet2 = xlWorkBook2.Sheets("Sheet2")

        Dim xlShp As Excel.Shape = Nothing
        Dim xlShape As Excel.Shape = Nothing

        For Each xlShp In xlWorkSheet1.Shapes
            xlShp.Copy()
            xlWorkSheet2.Paste(Destination:=xlWorkSheet2.Range("A1"))
        Next

        Dim col1 As New Point(10, 10)
        Dim col2 As New Point(col1.X * 2 + xlWorkSheet2.Shapes(0).Width, 10)
        Dim stdHeight As Integer = CType(xlWorkSheet2.Shapes(0), Excel.Shape).Height + 5

        For i As Integer = 0 To xlWorkSheet2.Shapes.Count - 1 Step 2
            xlShape = xlWorkSheet2.Shapes(i)
            xlShape.Left = col1.X
            xlShape.Top = col1.Y + i * stdHeight

            xlShape = xlWorkSheet2.Shapes(i + 1)
            xlShape.Left = col2.X
            xlShape.Top = col2.Y + i * stdHeight
        Next

        '~~> Save the file
        xlWorkBook2.Save()

        '~~> Close the File
        xlWorkBook1.Close (False)
        xlWorkBook2.Close (False)

        '~~> Quit the Excel Application
        xlApp.Quit()

        '~~> Clean Up
        releaseObject (xlShp)
        releaseObject (xlShape)
        releaseObject (xlWorkSheet1)
        releaseObject (xlWorkSheet2)
        releaseObject (xlWorkBook1)
        releaseObject (xlWorkBook2)

        releaseObject (xlApp)
    End Sub

    '~~> Release the objects
    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject (obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Workbook 2 Output**

[image]